# Grant Select on DMV's causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to give access to DM Views to a particular User.

Hence I tried to grant `VIEW DATABASE STATE` and  `VIEW SERVER STATE`  and an `EXECUTE` on the SP which is querying on sys.dm_exec_query_stats.

It did not work and I tried to Grant `SELECT` on specified DMV.

I am getting error `'Cannot find the user <UserName>, because it does not exist or you do not have permission.'`
Everything in the below script is working fine with the specified user but the last statement i.e Grant Select. 
Any guesses why ?

```
Use MyDatabase
GRANT EXECUTE ON [MySchema].[SP_MySPROC] TO UserName
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO UserName

USE master;
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO UserName
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dm_exec_query_stats TO UserName
```

Comment: Are you missing the `GRANT SELECT` segment in your example code? Does all the above code work otherwise?

Comment: Yes it does, and I did update the code to include select. Updating it again.

Comment: Is `UserName` a server principal or a database principal? Is there a chance that `UserName` is a database principal and doesn't exist in `master`?

Comment: I am really new to this DBA stuff. but I can see the username when I fire this query, which I assume is showing all the Server Principal.  Select name,principal_id from sys.server_principals

Comment: Note that you should not begin a user stored procedure name with `sp_`.  That prefix is reserved for system stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specified UserName must be a database principal (database user), not a server principal (login).  I expect explicitly adding the user to the master database will solve the GRANT problem, but you might instead consider signing the proc with a certificate that provides the needed permissions.  The certificate method is a more complex but more secure.  Below is a certificate example.

```
USE master;

-- create master database access certificate
CREATE CERTIFICATE MasterDatabaseUserCertificate
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ksfd78#$%@8ks1@b@'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Master database access certificate',
   START_DATE = '20020101', EXPIRY_DATE = '20990101';
GO

-- create the certificate login to assign server permissions
CREATE LOGIN MasterDatabaseUserCertificateLogin
    FROM CERTIFICATE MasterDatabaseUserCertificate;
GO

-- create the certificate user to assign database permissions
CREATE USER MasterDatabaseUserCertificateUser
    FOR LOGIN MasterDatabaseUserCertificateLogin;
GO

--grant server permissions
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO MasterDatabaseUserCertificateLogin;
GO

--grant database permissions
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dm_exec_query_stats TO MasterDatabaseUserCertificateUser;
GO

--export certificate to file
BACKUP CERTIFICATE MasterDatabaseUserCertificate
    TO FILE = 'C:\temp\YourCertificate.cer'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'C:\temp\MasterDatabaseUserCertificate.pvk' ,
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ksfd78#$%@8ks1@b@',
        DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ksfd78#$%@8ks1@b@');
GO

USE MyDatabase;
GO

-- import the certificate from file
CREATE CERTIFICATE MasterDatabaseUserCertificate
    FROM FILE = 'C:\temp\YourCertificate.cer'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'C:\temp\MasterDatabaseUserCertificate.pvk' ,
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ksfd78#$%@8ks1@b@',
        DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ksfd78#$%@8ks1@b@');
GO

-- sign procedure with certificate
ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.usp_MySPROC BY CERTIFICATE MasterDatabaseUserCertificate
    WITH PASSWORD = 'ksfd78#$%@8ks1@b@';
GO
```

Comment: Thanks ! I added it to master database by using User mapping in Server Login property page. And the Grant Select statement executed successfully. So all Grants in above script are done. and I am still getting Error saying 'The user does not have permission to perform this action.'

Comment: This is how I am trying to access the Sproc.                 EXECUTE AS USER = Username
EXEC [MySchema].[MySproc]  
REVERT

Comment: EXECUTE AS user is sandboxed to the current database and will not be honored in the other database.  If you don't want to add the invoking user to master, I suggest the certificate method.

Comment: I'll try certificate method.Thanks !

Comment: I added a certificate example script to my answer.